# Cumulative total from user's input string

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

I have tried to write a function that takes sequence of integers as input from the user and returns cumulative totals. For example, if the input is `1 7 2 9`, the function should print `1 8 10 19`. My program isn't working. Here is the code:

```
x=input("ENTER NUMBERS: ")
total  = 0
for v in x:
    total = total + v
    print(total)
```

and here is the output:

```
ENTER NUMBERS: 1 2 3 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\MANI\Desktop\cumulative total.py", line 4, in <module>
total = total + v
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I don't know what this error means. Please help me to debug my code.

Comment: Look at your error message: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`. What does this suggest is an issue, and what steps could you take to understand and fix it?

Comment: Could you please reword your question a bit? As it is, it sounds a bit like a [gimme teh codez](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged) question, and those aren't encouraged on this site. However, high quality questions get you reputation, which gives you more privileges on the site.

Comment: Don't let downvotes discourage you, you can improve this question. Just click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35827634/edit) button.

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. Remember: read the code and learn how it works.

```
x = input("Enter numbers: ") #Take input from the user
list = x.split(" ")          #Split it into a list, where
                             #a space is the separator
total = 0                    #Set total to 0
for v in list:               #For each list item
    total += int(v)          #See below for explanation
    print(total)             #Print the total so far
```

There are two new things in this code:

- `x.split(y)` splits `x` up into a list of smaller strings, using `y` as the separator. For example, `"1 7 2 9".split(" ")` returns ["1", "7", "2", "9"].
- `total += int(v)` is more complicated. I'll break it down more:

  - The `split()` function gave us an array of strings, but we want numbers. The `int()` function (among other things) converts a string to a number. That way, we can add it.
  - The `+=` operator means "increment by". Writing `x += y` is the same as writing `x = x + y` but takes less time to type.

There is another problem with the code: You say you need a function, but this is not a function. A function might look like this:

```
function cumulative(list):
    total = 0
    outlist = []
    for v in list:
       total += int(v)
       outlist.append(total)
    return outlist
```

and to use it:

```
x = input("Enter numbers: ").split(" ")
output = cumulative(x)
print(output)
```

but the program will work just fine.

Comment: THANKS BRO.. IT WORKS PERFECTLY.. U SOLVED MY PROBLEM :)

Comment: You're welcome. There is a tick beside each of the answers to your question. Put the tick next to the answer that worked the best to Mark as Answer.

Comment: And remember: Don't just ask; answer too! :-)

Comment: bro i haven't earned 15 points yet. so i m unable to put that tick. and yeah sure i will answer:)

Comment: @KhozemaKhanLodhi If you need any help with **anything**, just ask! d:-D

Comment: can you help me with how to check if the user's entered string is camel case or not? :P

Comment: @KhozemaKhanLodhi Unless you have a dictionary of all possible words, the best you can do is make sure there is one capital at the start and there aren't two capitals in a row.

Comment: Maybe you could ask a question: Check if string is camel case. (If you do, could you post a link?)

Comment: i have already checked that just need to know how to convert the string into camel case

Comment: @KhozemaKhanLodhi Do you mean converting something with spaces into camel case (e.g. `This example text` into `ThisExampleText`)? To do that, just split the string by spaces... Actually, just [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)! This isn't the place for me to answer it! :-)

Comment: @KhozemaKhanLodhi Oh, and a tip: don't ask for programs. Ask how to do something specific, not for a program that inputs and outputs too!

Answer (score 0):

## Cumulative totals

```
input_set = []
input_num = 0

while (input_num >= 0):

    input_num = int(input("Please enter a number or -1 to finish"))
    if (input_num < 0):
        break
    input_set.append(input_num)

print(input_set)

sum = 0
new_list=[]

for i in range(len(input_set)):
    sum = sum + input_set[i]
    new_list.append(sum)

print(new_list)
```